# html css positioning not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a multi-level mega menu like amazon but different in design and perspective. The problem I am facing is that once I hover on one sub-menu item the positioning of the relative menu items are not displayed properly. And if I hover on another item the positioning is a bit below the previous one.

Also I am using an external js resource. Please check the external resource in the fiddle.

I want the 2nd-level sub menu items inside the and correctly placed one above the other. And this goes one more level deeper.

```
    #menu li .align_right {
    position: relative;
    top: 1%;
    left: 350%;
}
#menu li:hover .align_right {
    top: 1%;
    left: 350%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Now even if I use absolute to the relative positioning, the li items doesn't align properly. Also I can't use `position: fixed;` because it will float on the web-page when scrolled even a little bit.

js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/neerajsonar/hzoyddhs/

result full screen - http://jsfiddle.net/neerajsonar/hzoyddhs/embedded/result/

Comment: Relevant code has to be posted in question itself

Comment: Yes, I am still writing the question. It got posted by mistake. I am editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Just having a quick look I see your CSS moves it left **350%**.
Change this to **350px** and it will keep the sub menu in the main area you want it.

```
#menu li:hover .align_right {
background: #94A6CE;
top: 1%;
left: 350px;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. it did help, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/neerajsonar/hzoyddhs/  
Now what happens is that the particular sub-menu-items li gets displayed on the same position of its parent. I don't want that. You can see the fiddle and make out the defect in it. The second sub-menu-items li gets displayed over the previous, that's fine I don't mind that as long as it completely hides the previous one.

Comment: Hi there, each sub menu should show and hide when mouseover and mouseout. It seems that the jquery being used for 'amazonmenu' allows it show but does not remove it on mouseout. Look into this area first, get it working correctly and then move on to the next issue. THat Fiddle link still uses the 350% rather than the 350px.